# Why are the jQuery functions only working the first time they're called?

Tags: ajax, jquery

There is a link that, when clicked, toggles between loading HTML into a div and emptying the div. When the div is clicked to load the html, I use the jQuery ajax load() function. When the text is loading, I want to display "Please wait...", so I tried using the jQuery ajaxStart() and ajaxStop() methods, but they only seemed to work the first time the load() function was called. So I switched to ajaxSend() and ajaxSuccess, but that also only seems to work the first time the load function is called. What's wrong?

HTML:

```
<p id="toggleDetail" class="link">Toggle Inspection Detail</p>
<p id="wait"></p>
<div id="inspectionDetail"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(
    function(){
        $('#toggleDetail').click(function(){
            if($.trim($('#inspectionDetail').text()).length)
            {
                $('#inspectionDetail').empty();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#inspectionDetail').load('srInspectionDetailFiller.cfm');
            }
        });
    }           
);

$(
    function(){
        $('#wait').ajaxSend(function() {
            $(this).text('Please wait...');
        });
    }
);
$(
    function(){
        $('#wait').ajaxSuccess(function() {
            $(this).text('');
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: While I'm not sure it's the way I'd have done it, your code does seem to work for me: [Unchanged except for faking the Ajax call, on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9rba/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put up the 'Please wait...' message in your `click` function, then clear the message upon successful completion of your `load`:

```
$('#toggleDetail').click(function(){
    if($.trim($('#inspectionDetail').text()).length)
    {
        $('#inspectionDetail').empty();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#wait').text('Please wait...');
        $('#inspectionDetail').load('srInspectionDetailFiller.cfm', function() {
                $('#wait').text('');
        });
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Although `ajaxSend` should technically work here, I don't recommend it. With `ajaxSend`, *"All ajaxSend handlers are invoked, regardless of what Ajax request is to be sent"*. It seem overkill to me to hook all Ajax requests on the page which you're really only trying to deal with this single click.